# Assembly Language Program for Detecting Prime Numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to write a program in assembly language to detect whether an input number is prime or not within the range of 0-9. I have written the program, but even though it runs, it does not function probably and I cannot pinpoint where the mistake is or why it is performing this way. Any advice would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.
`

```
.MODEL  SMALL

    .DATA
           VAl1     DB      ?
           NL1      DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
           NL2      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS NOT PRIME','$'
           NL3      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS PRIME','$'

           .CODE
       ORG 0100H
    MAIN:

            MOV AX,@DATA
            MOV DS,AX

            MOV DX,OFFSET NL1
            MOV AH,09H
            INT 21H
    
            MOV AH,01H
            INT 21H
            SUB AL,30H
            MOV VAL1,AL
            
            MOV AH,00

            MOV CL,2
            DIV CL
            MOV CL,AL

    LBL1:
            MOV AH,00
            MOV AL,VAL1
            DIV CL
            CMP AH,00
            JZ LBL2
            DEC CL
            CMP CL,1
            JNE LBL1
            JMP LBL3
    
    LBL2:
    
            MOV AH,09H
            MOV DX,OFFSET NL2
            INT 21H
            JMP EXIT    
    
    LBL3:
            MOV AH,09H
            MOV DX, OFFSETNL3
            INT 21H
    
    EXIT:
            MOV AH,4CH
            INT 21H
    
  END     MAIN
```

`

I am trying to detect whether a number is prime, but it is showing incorrect answers.

Comment: "Inorrect answers" is not a good problem description. What did you test with? "I cannot pinpoint where the mistake is" have you single stepped the code in the debugger? PS: your code only seems to test divisibility by 2.

Comment: I think it starts from VAL1/2 as a divisor, counting down until `VAL1 % 1 == 0`.  You can count up until `VAL1 / trial_divisor <= trial_divisor`, i.e. stop at the square root.  See [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965)

Comment: Ah yeah missed the initial division.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be if the input is less than 4 due to then `CL` ending up either 1 or 0 which is not checked before continuing to `LBL1`. Also 0 and 1 are not normally considered prime. Here is a minimal fix:

```
.MODEL  SMALL

.DATA
       VAl1     DB      ?
       NL1      DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
       NL2      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS NOT PRIME','$'
       NL3      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS PRIME','$'

       .CODE
   ORG 0100H
MAIN:

        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        MOV DX,OFFSET NL1
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        SUB AL,30H
        MOV VAL1,AL
        CMP AL, 2
        JB LBL2 ; 0,1 are not prime
        JE LBL3 ; 2 is prime
        
        MOV AH,00

        MOV CL,2
        DIV CL
        MOV CL,AL
        JMP LBL4 ; check CL

LBL1:
        MOV AH,00
        MOV AL,VAL1
        DIV CL
        CMP AH,00
        JZ LBL2
        DEC CL
LBL4:
        CMP CL,1
        JNE LBL1
        JMP LBL3

LBL2:

        MOV AH,09H
        MOV DX,OFFSET NL2
        INT 21H
        JMP EXIT    

LBL3:
        MOV AH,09H
        MOV DX, OFFSETNL3
        INT 21H

EXIT:
        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H

END     MAIN
```

If you can use the fact that you only need to handle 0-9 the code can be simplified further to maybe:

```
.MODEL  SMALL

.DATA
       NL1      DB      0AH,0DH,'ENTER NO:','$'
       NL2      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS NOT PRIME','$'
       NL3      DB      0AH,0DH,'IT IS PRIME','$'

       .CODE
   ORG 0100H
MAIN:

        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        MOV DX,OFFSET NL1
        MOV AH,09H
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        CMP AL, 32H
        JB LBL2 ; 0,1 are not prime
        JE LBL3 ; 2 is prime
        TEST AL, 1
        JZ LBL2 ; even numbers 4,6,8 not prime
        CMP AL, 39H
        JNE LBL3 ; odd except 9 is prime 
LBL2:

        MOV AH,09H
        MOV DX,OFFSET NL2
        INT 21H
        JMP EXIT    

LBL3:
        MOV AH,09H
        MOV DX, OFFSETNL3
        INT 21H

EXIT:
        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H

END     MAIN
```